# How to use mysql_plugin utility?

Tags: mysql, authentication, authorization, mariadb-10.3, plugins

I tried to follow [this](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysql_plugin/) official documentation to install unix_socket plugin using mysql_plugin utility but getting an error that

> Cannot read plugin config file unix_socket. Bad format in plugin
>   configuration file.

```
FROM alpine:edge

RUN set -ex \
&& apk add mariadb mariadb-client \
&& mysql_install_db --user=mysql --skip-name-resolve \
&& echo 'auth_socket' >> /usr/lib/mariadb/plugin/unix_socket.ini  \
&& mysql_plugin --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin_dir=/usr/lib/mariadb/plugin unix_socket ENABLE   

CMD ["mysqld"]
```

I cross checked the ini file.

```
cat /usr/lib/mariadb/plugin/unix_socket.ini
auth_socket
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .ini needs to contain the plugin followed by the components.

The document [Authentication Plugin - Unix Socket](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/) hints that the component name is `unix_socket`.

So the correct contents of the file should be:

`echo -e 'auth_socket\nunix_socket' >> /usr/lib/mariadb/plugin/unix_socket.ini`

As a workaround use `plugin-load=auth_socket` in /etc/my.cnf.d/mariadb-server.cnf seems also sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for creating the issue. https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-18206

Comment: The bug wouldn't have been notice by the development team otherwise. 10.4 adds [INSTALL PLUGIN IF NOT EXISTS](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/install-plugin/). I admittedly hadn't come across mysql_plugin before.